# is $Hom(P,N \otimes_{End(P)} P) = N$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, modules, derived-functors

This is probably well known to people who work with algebras but I couldn't find a reference.

Say I have a ring A and a module P and I take B = End(P), the endomorphism ring. Let N be a B-module, is it true that

> $Hom_A(P, N\otimes_B P) = N$?

maybe I want to assume for N and P to be projective (over B and over A respectively).

Is this still true if now A is a dg-algebra (or simplicial algebra or ring spectrum or...) and in the identity above everything is derived?

The reason I think it's plausible is because morally

$$ Hom_A(P, N \otimes_B P) = (N \otimes_B P) \otimes_A P^\vee = N \otimes_B B $$

but I want to make sure I haven't "cheated" with the identity above.

thanks

Comment: $N$ is a *right* $B$-module?

Comment: @Bernard I always get left and right confused, but I think that it should indeed be a right module.

Comment: There exists a homorphism from $\,\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,P)\otimes_BN\,$ to  $\,\operatorname{Hom}_A(P,P\otimes_BN)$, ig $N$ is a *left* $B$-modules, and if $P$ can be considered an $(A,B)$-bimodule (to be checked). This homomorphism is an isomorphism if $P$ is a finitely generated projective $A$-module. Reference: *Bourbaki, Algebra, Ch. 1, Linear algebra*, §4 no.2, Prop. 2.

Comment: @Bernard sweet, bourbaki rulez. I'll double check my left and right modules but that's gotta be it. thanks.